# Github - Create a repo failed

Tags: github

I want to create a repo, but I failed. Here are my steps:

```
mkdir ~/Hello-World
cd ~/Hello-World
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'  --> 1 file changed, 1 insertion
git push origin master
```

I am asked for my password and username, which I entered.

```
fatal :https://github.com/timokoerner/Hello-World.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack not found; did you run git update server info
```

I have git version 1.8. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- replace your current remote named origin with the name of an *existing* GitHub repo

  ```
  git remote set-url origin https://github.com/timokoerner/Xing.git
  ```
- try a `git push -u origin master` for your first push.
  See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".
  After that first push, other commits can be publised with a single '`git push`'.

Comment: These commands are handy and I will try it.

Comment: @Timo More than eight years after having written that answer, that is good to know :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I've never had a problem with creating an initial repo on Github.

Try going here and filling out the necessary fields:

[Create Github Repo](https://github.com/new)

Once that's done, you can use `git clone` to create a local instance of the repo. From there, you can push and pull from it like a normal repository.

Comment: I tried the create Repo, entered `git remote add origin https://github.com/timokoerner/Xing.git`, I got the msg: fatal - remote origin already exists. After `git push` I receive the same message as above. I changed my pwd, so it should not be the problem. Any idea ?

Comment: I would recommend deleting your local repo and retrying `git clone`.

Answer (score 1):

You typed a wrong Username or Password.

Comment: User-Name or should be ok, because updating the file in an existing repo with `git commit -a <filename>` and then `git push` works well, because I am asked to enter these two.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enter your GitHub username and GitHub password?

You can also edit the remote so it points to `https://timokoerner@github.com/timokoerner/Xing.git`. That will just prompt you for your (GitHub) password in that case.

Comment: I think this remote format is wrong, correct is `https://github.com/bakkdoor/grit (fetch)`, [see](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

Answer (score 1):

The "-u" is necessary.

> git init
>
> Create a .gitignore file in include all files and directories that you
>   don't want to commit
>
> git add . //add all files to local git
>
> git status -a / show all files that are modified or added
>
> git remote add origin git@github.com:USER/REPO.git
>
> git push -u origin master