# Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?

Tags: git, version-control

I am new in `git` and I am practicing. I created a local branch but I saw that when I did `git push` my branch was not uploaded to the repository. I had to actually do: `git push -u origin --all`.
Why is this? Isn't a branch a new change to be pushed by default? Why do I need to run the second command?

Comment: Note that this is configurable (setting `push.default`, see `man git-config`). If you do `git config --add push.default current`, then `git push` will automatically create the branch in the remote repo if necessary. Why this is not the default is explained in the answers.

Comment: @sleske I agree. For the other policies '`current`' and '`upstream`', see my older answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13751847/6309.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

The actual reason is that, in a new repo (git init), there **is no branch** (no `master`, no branch at all, zero branches)

So when you are pushing for the first time to an *empty* [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) (generally a [bare one](http://web.archive.org/web/20130820233326/http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html)), that upstream repo has no branch of the same name.

And:

- the [default push policy was '`matching`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13886400/6309) (push all the branches of the same name, creating them if they don't exist),
- the default push policy [is now '`simple`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002469/6309) (push only the current branch, and only if it has a similarly named [remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070851/6309) on upstream, [since git 1.7.11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15598713/6309))

In both cases, since the upstream empty repo has no branch:

- there is no matching named branch yet
- there is no upstream branch at all (with or without the same name! Tracking or not)

That means your local *first* push has no idea:

- where to push
- what to push (since it cannot find any upstream branch being either recorded as a remote tracking branch, and/or having the same name)

So you need at least to do a:

```
git push origin master
```

But if you do only that, you:

- will create an upstream `master` branch on the upstream (now non-empty repo): good.
- won't *record* that the local branch '`master`' needs to be pushed to upstream (`origin`) '`master`' (upstream branch): bad.

That is why it is recommended, for the first push, to do a:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Or, [using Git 2.37 and the new global option `push.autoSetupRemote`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/6309) :

```
git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true
git push
```

That will record `origin/master` as a [remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046478/6309), and will enable the next push to automatically push `master` to `origin/master`.

```
git checkout master
# Git 2.23+
git switch master
git push
```

And that will work too with push policies '`current`' or '`upstream`'.
In each case, after the initial `git push -u origin master`, a simple git push will be enough to continue pushing `master` to the right upstream branch.

Comment: After this point, the next `git push` also expects the branch to already exist?

Comment: Yes. It will push any updates to that branch to upstream repository.

Comment: @Cratylus yes, because of the new default push policy '`simple`': push to any recorded upstream branch, *if* that upstream branch has the same name as the local one. A simple `git push` will be enough.

Comment: Suppose i had used `git push origin master` for the first time, how do i subsequently mark `origin/master` as a remote tracking branch? Can i still use `git push -u origin master` when the remote branch already exists and has been pushed to before?

Comment: How to remember this solution: Just follow the helpful git output after an unsuccessful `git push`. It proposes `git push --set-upstream origin master`, which is the long version for `git push -u origin master`.

Comment: @VonC the link seems to say it doesn't apply for Git above v1.7. Is it ok to use a non-bare repo with Git 2.3?

Comment: @ButtleButkus Git 2.3 is actually ok: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28381311/6309

Comment: For the questioner's more general case of a new branch 'new_branch', you would use `git push --set-upstream origin new_branch` or `git push -u origin new_branch` for short. The `-all` that the questioner used bypassed naming a specific new branch by including all branches. This is covered by +Klas Mellbourn in his answer.

Comment: The -u is shorthand for the suggestion that git (ver 2.20) gives you when you try to push a branch upstream and there is no matching branch. It's shorthand for  --set-upstream

Answer (score 121):

**You don't, see below**

I find this 'feature' rather annoying since I'm not trying to launch rockets to the moon, just push my damn branch. You probably do too or else you wouldn't be here!

Here is the fix: if you want it to implicitly push for the current branch regardless of if that branch exists on origin just issue this command once and you will **never** have to again anywhere:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

So if you make branches like this:

```
git checkout -b my-new-branch
```

and then make some commits and then do a

```
git push -u
```

to get them out to origin (being on that branch) and it will create said branch for you if it doesn't exist.

Note the -u bit makes sure they are linked if you were to pull later on from said branch. If you have no plans to pull the branch later (or are okay with another one liner if you do) -u is not necessary.

Comment: When I do this, if I do a git pull, immediately after - the two branches aren't linked. :(

Comment: this is the only answer that fixed my problem.

Comment: To link them, use `git push -u`

Comment: Thanks! This answer ought to be accepted as the quick-and-'dirty' solution. I'm pretty sure it's closest to what OP's intention.

Comment: > I'm not trying to launch rockets to the moon. -- 
YES.

Answer (score 43):

Output of `git push` when pushing a new branch

```
> git checkout -b new_branch
Switched to a new branch 'new_branch'
> git push
fatal: The current branch new_branch has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin new_branch
```

A simple `git push` assumes that there already exists a remote branch that the current local branch is tracking. If no such remote branch exists, and you want to create it, you must specify that using the `-u` (short form of `--set-upstream`) flag.

Why this is so? I guess the implementers felt that creating a branch on the remote is such a major action that it should be hard to do it by mistake. `git push` is something you do all the time.

"Isn't a branch a new change to be pushed by default?" I would say that "a change" in Git is a commit. A branch is a pointer to a commit. To me it makes more sense to think of a push as something that pushes commits over to the other repositories. Which commits are pushed is determined by what branch you are on and the tracking relationship of that branch to branches on the remote.

You can read more about tracking branches in the [Remote Branches chapter of the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).

Comment: I did not get a `fatal` but I had already done a commit in the branch.Does this matter?

Comment: @Cratylus no it does not matter. The commit is safe in your repository, and the `git push -u origin` copied it over to the remote repository.

Comment: No I mean the fact that I did not get a `fatal` msg like the one that you mention in the answer.Does this difference depend on the fact that I committed something to the branch?

Comment: @Cratylus I don't know why you did not get the `fatal` message. I would guess that the difference depends on exactly what git implementation you are using. My output is from 1.8.1.msysgit.1 running on Windows 8.

Comment: I have the same version but on Vista

Comment: @Cratylus I get the `fatal` message even if I make a commit.

Comment: If I `checkout -b name` and commit a file my `HEAD` is in `name`.If I do `git push` I get: `warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use: etc` and then `Everything up-to-date`

Comment: @Cratylus You can avoid that message by doing `git config --global push.default simple`. The reason you got `Everything up-to-date` must be that there already was a `name` branch on the remote that is now tracked by your local `name` branch.

Comment: Ok. But why is it not `fatal`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31738/discussion-between-klas-mellbourn-and-cratylus)

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find a rationale by the original developers this quickly, but I can give you an educated guess based on a few years of Git experience.

No, not every branch is something you want to push to the outside world. It might represent a private experiment.

Moreover, where should `git push` send all the branches? Git can work with multiple remotes and you may want to have different sets of branches on each. E.g. a central project GitHub repo may have release branches; a GitHub fork may have topic branches for review; and a local Git server may have branches containing local configuration. If `git push` would push all branches to the remote that the current branch tracks, this kind of scheme would be easy to screw up.

Comment: 1)`It might represent a private experiment`.Ok but what is the big deal? The "main" branch that everyone is working i.e. `master` is not affected. Unless you mean to keep the source code hidden 2)`git push, without a remote, pushes to the current branch's remote` I lost you here :(

Comment: @Cratylus: 1) in a project with dozens of developers who all branch ad lib, you're going to get very messy repos. I work on such projects, and I wouldn't want to `git fetch` hundreds of half-working branches every time. 2) I'm referring to `git push`'s default behavior. It pushes to the remote that the current branch is tracking, if any.

Answer (score 3):

HEAD is short for current branch so git push -u origin HEAD works. Now to avoid this typing everytime I use alias:

**git config --global alias.pp 'push -u origin HEAD'**

After this, everytime I want to push branch created via git -b branch I can push it using:

**git pp**

Hope this saves time for someone!

Answer (score 2):

At first check

Step-1: `git remote -v`
//if found git initialize then remove or skip step-2

Step-2: `git remote rm origin`
//Then configure your email address globally git

Step-3: `git config --global user.email "youremail@example.com"`

Step-4: `git initial`

Step-5: `git commit -m "Initial Project"`
//If already add project repo then skip step-6

Step-6: `git remote add origin %repo link from bitbucket.org%`

Step-7: `git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced a further permutation of this issue.

I had a branch named `feat/XYZ-1234-some-description` because I was working on Jira  issue 1234. During the work I created a new Jira issue to track a smaller piece of work, and when I came to push I decided to push to a branch name with this new issue number in:

```sh
git push -u origin feat/XYZ-5678-a-different-description # failed
```

This gave me the error being discussed in this SO thread. But since I was trying to push to a *different* branch name from my current branch, my problem was different to the one described here. I ended up renaming my local branch before I could push it:

```sh
git branch -m feat/XYZ-1234-some-description feat/XYZ-5678-a-different-description
git push -u origin feat/XYZ-5678-a-different-description # now works
```

After a bit more reading around I realised that I could have set a `src` on the 
`git push`, either to the current branch name, or just `HEAD` if appropriate:

```sh
git push -u origin feat/XYZ-1234-some-description:feat/XYZ-5678-a-different-description # also works
```

Answer (score -1):

If you enable to push new changes from your new branch first time.
And getting below error:

```
*git push -f
fatal: The current branch Coding_Preparation has no upstream branch.
```

To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

```
git push -u origin new_branch_name


** Successful Result:** 
 git push -u origin Coding_Preparation
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 599 bytes | 599.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: Create a pull request for 'Coding_Preparation' on GitHub by visiting: ...
 * [new branch]      Coding_Preparation -> Coding_Preparation
Branch 'Coding_Preparation' set up to track remote branch 'Coding_Preparation' from 'origin'.
```