# Stuck at push, nothing happens

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-clone

i used git before without any problem, but suddenly i can't **push** or **clone** anything.
when i use this command, just nothing happens, not even an error, so i have to press **ctrl + c** or just close git window.
i use this simple command for pushing:

```
git push origin master
```

also tried with **-u** parameter.

1. i opened port 22 in my firewall, no luck
2. i use both http and ssh, again no luck
3. i install a new version of git, no luck

so what i can do to solve this?

**Update:**

i installed a fresh win xp on virtual machine and test to **push** something, same result as before, so may be my internet connection have some problem.

any idea?

Comment: No error?  what output *do* you get?

Comment: nothing, just a blinking cursor, no matter how long i wait.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a problem with git; anything else crazy happening on your machine?

Comment: i don't know, yesterday it worked fine, now it doesn't. i just install NODEJS, and jitsu cli since then, is it possible that make problem? i don't think so.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I have exactly the same problem, simply trying to push a local working directory to a fresh github repo

Comment: @Anh: in my case the problem was from github and it solved by itself, maybe one or 2 days after the problem appears.

Comment: Check out this article to set up ssh: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

I also had to set up git to disable verifying SSL: 
>$ GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git push

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Update 2021: this is again an issue, when pushing with HTTPS URL, with Git 2.32 (June 2021).

See [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68057563/6309): there is a bug with the Microsoft Git Credential Manager Core, which is why, as [Pinak Ganguly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16373948/pinak-ganguly) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68239912/6309), you might want to switch temporarely to the obsolete Git Credential Manager:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

---

First, there was some issue with [ssh access recently](https://status.github.com/messages):

> We are currently investigating SSH access problems on one of our fileserver pairs. A small number of repositories may be affected.

Second, you would need to try and use https, not http:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/reponame
```

Third, the `git push -u origin master` is only for the first push (after that, `git push` alone is enough: see "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)" for more)

If the push or clone issue still persists, then you need to contact GitHub support to know more about this.

Comment: wow! this saved me from spending another 2 hours!
The same thing happened on mac (m1) but setting up the remote url and re-creating the access token worked.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a little out of the box thinking.

Do you have a VPN on?

#### Close all of your applications including the VPN and terminal then try again.

It is amazing how many times just turning things off then on has helped at times, sometimes things just get stuck and need a "power start" may it serve you as well too.

Comment: This happened for me. I closed VPN and everything works fine.

Comment: I was working on university project and It requires to be connected with university vpn. Thanks I just connect to VPN and everything now works well.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the https connection was not working.
Change remote origin url, not using https but git

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git
```

This url can be found on your github or gitlab project page

Answer (score 2):

I had messed with multiple repositories and for some reason, the force argument solved the problem.

```
git push --force origin master
```

Comment: It worked with me too, same problem and get stuck at Total....pack reused 0.
Maybe it is a problem of branchs in your system idk i didn't use a master branch ...

Answer (score 1):

Add

`git remote set-url "https://github.com/targetusername/targetrepo"`

after

`git remote add "https://github.com/targetusername/targetrepo"`

and before

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to contribute yet another reason this can happen: if the remote you're pushing to has IP filters in place, it will blink with no output. In my case, my laptop was connected with WiFi which was not connecting through a whitelisted IP address.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the root cause might be the underlying network devices/drivers. Try rebooting your machine; or as a workaround add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
IPQoS lowdelay throughput
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the installation may be with the latest GIT version(2.32.0).

To fix it, you have to reinstall git and select the highlighted option when [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKQ0k.png) comes up.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe be related to yout ssh client. Can you ssh login the a remote server? The `-v` verbose option is very usefull here.

```
ssh -v -p PORT USER@SERVER
```

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60205342/195812

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have faced the same problem and I solved the problem following bellow steps

1. Make sure you have put the correct user name and email.

   ```
   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
   git config --global user.email "youremail@gmail.com"
   ```
2. Now run this command

   ```
   git config --list
   ```
3. You will see the output like this

   ```
   user.name=Your Name
   user.email=youremail@gmail.com
   ```
4. Finally it works for me

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "youremail@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

Follow @VonC's solution.
I got the stuck while doing git push and git pull, this works for me.

Comment: Whilst your answer is useful, it helps to add more context and information to make the answer more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else made this silly mistake, I thought I had this issue but it was just because I wasn't used to the way VSCode asks for credentials in bash terminal now.

If you're using VSCode with bash terminal and you do git pull, it will just go to a new blank line, but it will also create a little form dialog at the very top of the screen asking for you to type your username, then password for the repository. I didn't see it because I was looking at the bottom of the screen where the terminal was. That and I'm on a very laggy XRDP session. Doh!