# Why does git pull hang?

Tags: git, git-bash, git-pull

When I do a `git pull`, from the git bash, the terminal usually runs the pull, updates my local, and then hangs. I'm not sure if it's waiting for me to do something, but I usually exit out of this with `CTRL-C`. After that, I get that an index.lock is preventing me from doing other things to which I have to delete it. Am I misunderstanding how `git pull` works?

Comment: In the terminal, execute as one statement `GIT_TRACE=true git pull`, and then see if you can see what it is doing when it hangs.

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, and if it is hanging during the `git merge` step, do you have some process running that is holding a lock on some file? Windows has "mandatory locking" in which if process *A* has a file locked, and process *B* (Git) tries to *use* that file, process *B* is paused until *A* releases the lock. If you terminate *B* (i.e., ^C out of Git), ideally it should clean up its `index.lock` file (which doesn't use Windows' mandatory locking, it's just an ordinary file Git uses to coordinate with itself), but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: In my case, it worked after closing cmder, vscode, and azure data studio. So one of them must've had a lock on a git-related file or something.

Answer (score 107):

You may need to remove unnecessary git objects such as `dangling commits & blobs`:

```
git fsck && git gc --prune=now
```

> [git-fsck](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) : Verifies the connectivity and validity of the objects in the database
>   [git-gc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) : Cleanup unnecessary files and optimize the local repository

You can [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514659/git-what-is-a-dangling-commit-blob-and-where-do-they-come-from) about `dangling commits & blobs`.

Comment: `git gc --prune=now` did it for me, though it did take about 10-15 minutes to finish. I ran it with `GIT_TRACE=true git gc --prune=now` to verify it was working and not permanently lagging. (`git fsck` lagged for me and didn't seem to help)

Answer (score 15):

As someone who does not use VS Code very often, I too thought git was hanging when I ran `git pull`. Turns out I was just not very observant. As illustrated in the image below, I was laser focused on the terminal and did not notice the prompt for a username which was the actual cause of the "hang".

[image: Perhaps it is not actually hanging after all]

Comment: Thank you, I just switched to main branch to update and noticed it asking for a password.

Comment: This is exactly the problem I had, thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Check SSH_AUTH_SOCK isn't pointing at a stale ssh-agent endpoint. Unset it (`unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK`) to test.

Comment: Thank you, This solved my problem after 2 hours of researching

Answer (score 11):

I am in Windows, and I solved the hang by closing the Visual Studio before doing the pull.

Comment: (On Mac OS X) I had Visual Studio Code opened and it hung on `git pull`. Closed it. Did `git pull` again and VS Code launched and opened a commit message for the `merge` that was needed because of the `git pull`. Entered a message, saved, closed the window and all was well.

Comment: I had issues with my network which was blocking the ssh connections, when I read your answer I realized that my problem can be other thing than what I was expecting to be.

Answer (score 10):

If you are pulling from a linux machine you may want to check this file:

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

To make sure you aren't setting your default SSH port to something other than 22. Some people get confused between that file and:

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

When they're setting up servers to a non-standard SSH port.

Comment: This was my issue, thank you for adding this comment!

Answer (score 9):

On Fedora 32, all git commands were hanging for me (only for repos on gitlab), solved with

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

leaving this here in case it helps anyone else

Comment: I had to run

```bash
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

on Pop_OS! for a GitLab repo too, worked fine for GitHub, very weird.

Comment: Same issue for me only with GitLab. Your suggestion resolved the issue for me too

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the problem was solved by switching ssh to use IPv4.

To do that, put `AddressFamily inet` string into `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Wow. It solved my problem too on my WSL2 Ubuntu terminal

Comment: git pull & git checkout hangs with bitbucket with ipv6 address, that config removed the problem

Answer (score 5):

Your ISP might be blocking the traffic. For example, VirginMedia in the UK does [something with a proxy](https://community.virginmedia.com/t5/Forum-Archive/GitHub-inaccesible-over-SSH/td-p/3816287) for their filters that causes GitHub traffic to hang. I had this issue, and disabling the filter fixed it.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! They've had this issue since 2018 and it still exists. Unbelievable!

Answer (score 2):

I updated git scm 2.32.0 to 2.33.1 version
and problem with hanging fetch, push, pull
was resolved

Comment: thanks! it's working,I just download the latest version of git that solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

For me, port 22 (SSH port) was blocked by the university I was visiting (affecting the eduroam network). Instead, I started using port 443 (HTTPS port). To diagnose if port 22 is blocked you may compare if `ssh -T -p 22 git@ssh.github.com` blocks and `ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com` gives a message.

For a single repo, my solution was to add an alternative remote I called origin443

```
git remote add origin443 ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/[USERNAME]/[REPO-NAME].git
```

To fix this problem regardless of repository you can update/add the ssh Github entry in your `~/.ssh/config` to always use 443 for Github. Use:

```
Host github.com
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    Port 443
    User git
```

For more information see [SSH over HTTPS](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port) on Github docs

Comment: I don't think that this is relevant as the question clearly mentions that donwloading refs work.

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, which was related to my ssh client.

This was confirmed trying to connect to a remote ssh server with the '-v' (verbose) option

```
ssh -v -p PORTNUMBER USERNAME@SERVER
```

which gave  `rekey after XXXXXX blocks”` before getting stuck.

`apt-get purge` and  `apt-get install`  didn't help, so - before facing the interestign approach here exposed  at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/280800  -  I went for an easy reboot, which did the job.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue while using VSCode. I solved it by toggling **off** and **on** the `GitHub: Git Authentication` setting (in User Settings (UI))

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the 'git pull' hangs in the vscode terminal(zsh), which cannot display the password prompt.
Using another shell (login via putty) other than in vscode to solve this problem

Comment: you can debug git pull from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178401/how-can-i-debug-git-git-shell-related-problems

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had changed my ssh config file and this repository was using a non-existent ssh config.

To check remote config:

```
git remote -v
```

To check ssh config:

```
cat ~/.ssh/config
```

To fix it, I had to remove remote and add a new one:

```
git remote add origin
git remote add origin right-ssh-config
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Linux, close and reopen the terminal and restart your ssh.
Enter the following code in the terminal, and try again.

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

ssh-add ~/.ssh/putHereYourSSHkey

ssh -T git@github.com
```

Comment: Can you add some detail about why you believe this will fix the issue?  Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When going through all the resources/domains under my `~/.git/config` I started to test/ping/telnet all domains, one of them - simply didn't answer, its IP was changed. that caused the entire `git pull` to hang...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried all the solutions described here in the other answers, and nothing worked. Then I noticed that I'm only having this problem with one repo, and other repos were working fine.
I double checked that there is no "index.lock" file for the repo that was having the problem. Then I just deleted the entire folder and re-cloned the repo. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

A potential cause is the sshCommand git config.

I've followed AlexS advice from below question:
[Git for Windows - Asking for SSH passphrase every push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66972638/git-for-windows-asking-for-ssh-passphrase-every-push)

It's by no means bad advice, but it's not universal. My pull started hanging after assigning the variable. I guess the file path wasn't correct for my machine.

Removing it from git config file solved the git pull hanging issue.

Answer (score 0):

for me it's waiting for me to input credentials. I didn't notice a git popup appears asking me for password

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was on a VPN. Turning it off fixed it