# git pull & git clone hang - Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, ssh, sshd

So lately, I update my SSH port to `558`

**cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep Po

Port 558**

I notice that my `git pull` keep hanging.

I research online, I found this SO link

[Why does git pull hang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44031150/why-does-git-pull-hang)

I tried

```
git fsck && git gc --prune=now
```

I got

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (3806/3806), done.
Counting objects: 3840, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (1566/1566), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3840/3840), done.
Total 3840 (delta 2120), reused 3795 (delta 2096)
```

---

I tried `git pull` again after that , hang again.

---

My VM have access to the internet.

```
ping google.com                                                                       
PING google.com (172.217.12.142) 56(84) bytes of data.                                    
64 bytes from lga34s19-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.12.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=1.68 ms  
64 bytes from lga34s19-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.12.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=1.31 ms  
64 bytes from lga34s19-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.12.142): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=1.11 ms  
^C                                                                                        
--- google.com ping statistics ---                                                        
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms                            
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.118/1.374/1.689/0.238 ms
```

---

This is my

```
└── git config --list                                                                     
core.repositoryformatversion=0                                                            
core.filemode=true                                                                        
core.bare=false                                                                           
core.logallrefupdates=true                                                                
remote.origin.url=git@bitbucket.org:bb/cc.git                               
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*                                   
branch.master.remote=origin                                                               
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master                                                     
remote.origin2.url=https://rajakannan@bitbucket.org/bb/cc.git
```

What should I check ?

---

## Update

I am not sure if it is related to my **sshd_config** or not, but

I tried

```
mkdir test
cd test


git clone git@bitbucket.bb/cc.git
Cloning into 'cc'...
|...
```

hang again ... even on clone

---

## Update 2

Could this be a firewall issues ? I can't even ping `bitbucket.org`

```
ping bitbucket.org
PING bitbucket.org (18.205.93.2) 56(84) bytes of data.

... stuck ... freeze ...
```

but I can `ping google.com`

```
ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.9.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga34s11-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.9.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=1.59 ms
64 bytes from lga34s11-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.9.238): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=1.27 ms
^C64 bytes from lga34s11-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.9.238): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=1.05 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.052/1.307/1.596/0.227 ms
```

Comment: Your sshd port change shouldn't affect git operations. Try re-cloning the repo to a different local directory and see if that helps.

Comment: I was reading this guys answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47057539/4480164 , that's why I was think it has something to do with sshd.

Comment: But anyway, let me try clone into the new dir/

Comment: @ShangjianDing : git clone, also hang;

Comment: Take Git out of the picture entirely: can you `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` at all? See https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html#SetupanSSHkey-ssh2

Comment: That command also hang ... `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`

Comment: I have no idea what is GOING on .. now. :(

Answer (score 1):

[BitBucket status](https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/)  is clean, so the issue is not on the remote side.

You are cloning with an SSH URL `git@bitbucket.org:bb/cc.git`.
Try, for testing, an HTTPS URL: https://bitbucket.org/bb/cc.git

Comment: I tried https clone, I kept getting `The requested URL returned error: 403` even with the right password that I used to login. I tested it.

Comment: @kyo So it does ask for a password? But returns 403?

Comment: It asked, I typed corrected password, it return 403.

Comment: @kyo Did it asked for your username as well (before the password)?

Comment: https always ask for password. Only `git` is not, since it doing via SSH.

Comment: @kyo But does it ask for your username first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206154/discussion-between-vonc-and-kyo).