# Git pull freeze Mac

Tags: git, ssh, git-pull

I am unable to execute `git pull` or `git clone` from the terminal or the terminal inside VSCode. I just get no feedback. I have repeatedly tried to change WIFI, restart laptop, restart VSCode, regenerate SSH Keys, without success. Also executed `git gc --prune=now --aggressive`, which did not help. Do you know what might be the issue and what else I could try?

[image]

**Update**

[image]

`unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK` did not help either, nor did **turning off the firewall**

Comment: Maybe this question can help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44031150/why-does-git-pull-hang

Comment: @JinoMichelAque I've updated the question based on what I tried from the link you've sent.

Comment: Maybe this will help see what's going on? [Really verbose way to test Git connection over SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/q/336907)

Comment: Tracing a little bit might help you see what is going on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706495/2437508

Comment: First: always prune away irrelevant stuff when testing, so that you don't test things you don't care about. The part that's hanging is presumably `git fetch`, so use `git fetch` rather than `git pull`: `git pull` runs *two* commands and you want to debug just *one*, not three total (pull plus the inner two). Second, check the URL that `git fetch` is fetching from, with `git remote -v`. If it's using https, try connecting from a browser or from the "curl" command. If it's ssh, try connecting from ssh. In other words, remove *Git* from the testing entirely!

Comment: If and when you've established that ssh or curl or whatever is able to contact the remote host (assuming there is a remote host), *then* introduce ssh and/or curl packet tracing as appropriate. If the problem is that you can't reach out over the net, focus in on that.

Comment: Who knows, it may turn out to be a new variant of the [500 mile email bug](https://web.mit.edu/jemorris/humor/500-miles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the latest Mac update to Monterey 12.15.1 broke the connection to github, so what I did to fix it in the end was to delete the Cisco AnyConnect Socket Filter app from my Mac, regenerate keys using `ssh-keygen -t ed25516 -C "your_email@example.com" -f $HOME/.ssh/id_ed25516` command, then place the `~/.ssh/id_ed25516` file contents in a new SSH Key on my github account.
After these changes, the `git pull` commands started working again.

Comment: I can confirm this, my git installation broke totally during the night. Had to update to Monterey 12.6, update Xcode and git to make it work again.