# Git push - nothing happens

Tags: git, bitbucket

First let me say that I tried this solution:
[Stuck at push, nothing happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129751/stuck-at-push-nothing-happens)

It does not work for me.

I created a repository on Bitbucket and added it as remote origin. After that I did standard procedure:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Initial update"
```

But when I try to do:

```
git push -u origin master
```

or

```
git push origin master
```

nothing happens. I do not even get an error message as output. It is just pending. And all I can do is stop the process with CTRL + C.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

After some time I got this error message:

> fatal: unable to access
>   'https://harunB@bitbucket.org/harunB/test.git/': Failed to connect to
>   bitbucket.org port 443: Connection refused

Comment: Why not use ssh instead? https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/ssh-keys-935365775.html --- Do you have permission to access the repo?

Comment: I've never usedd ssh before. I will try though. Yes, I do have a permission. I created the repo.

Comment: I'm seeing this too. I think every once in a while bitbucket goes off into la-la-land.

Comment: In my case it was due to DNS settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a networking issue - something is preventing your requests from getting to Bitbucket. It might be DNS (the actual Bitbucket IP addresses are listed on https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-are-the-bitbucket-cloud-ip-addresses-i-should-use-to-configure-my-corporate-firewall-343343385.html ), or a firewall, or your ISP, or you may need to provide proxy settings. Unfortunately, there isn't enough detail in "Connection refused" to say where the problem is.

Since you're using HTTPS, though, you should be able to use `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push` to see the full output of the command. That might help you track down the issue.