# Git: Nothing happens after pushing (git push)

Tags: git, gitlab, push

I want to push code to my repo on gitlab.
I am working on a lab PC, where I have to enter my credentials everytime i use fetch, pull or push. 
fetch and pull are working, but if I use git push, I can enter username and password and then nothing happens. just the cursor in a blank line. no error message. I have to ctrl-c to type a new command.
i also tried git push -u origin mybranch. same result.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem or an idea how to solve it? 
Best Regards,
Peter

Comment: Stuck at push, nothing happens
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129751/stuck-at-push-nothing-happens

Comment: I saw that and also tried the --force option, but it didn't help. I also think, the problem is not the connection, because git fetch is working

Comment: if you run `git remote -v` do you see the same URL for both fetch and push?

Comment: You are sure you commited first, right..? What does `git status` return..?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

It had to do with LFS (Large File System)
I didn't know anything about it, but all I had to do, was to delete 4 files in the git/hooks/ folder. 
It works now.