# VS Code github keeps showing Uploading files forever

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

The message keeps saying uploading files "forever". What I did was created a folder with a file inside. On Github, the repository was created successfully but the file is not uploading. And yes I have installed git.

[image]

The repository created successfully but the files are not uploading.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the [`latest Git for Windows`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), chances are you have a `git config credential.helper` set to `manager-core`.

As I mentioned in "[After `$git push -u origin main` command, Git bash is not requesting any authentication literally does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68057563/6309)", the same issue is seen in command-line, not just VSCode.

This is because of the Git-Credential-Manager-Core (interface to the Windows Credential Manager, in charge of caching your credentials: GitHub username/token).

Try and install the [last GCM-Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/releases) (released yesterday), and see if the issue persists then.

Or, alternatively, you could use an SSH URL, again, to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Well i am getting a new error saying "You do not have permission to push to "myCreatedRepository" on Github. Would you like to create a fork and push to it instead.?"

Comment: @AkmKawser That is expected if the remote URL used points to a Git repository which is not on your account. Or if it is, but using cached credentials which are not correct. What credentials do you see when opening the Windows Credential Manager? (as seen n https://davemateer.com/2019/07/28/Multiple-Github-Logins#delete-current-cache-of-github-passwords for instance)

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me:
In VSCode: File -> Preferences -> Settings.
Filter for "git".
Select "git (80)" on the left pane.
Uncheck this:

**Git: Require Git User Config**
*Controls whether to require explicit Git user configuration or allow Git to guess if missing*