# I tried to git code to github repo with git but it is not working

Tags: git

I have been trying to create a repo to github through git, but I couldn't do it, these are the steps I did:

```
git init
git add .
git commit
git push
```

and this is the message I get:

```
fatal: The current branch main has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin main
```

when I use the command I get nothing:

```
 git push --set-upstream origin main
```

another thing, sorry if it sounded stupid but I really want to understand, the first time I configured git on my PC it connected with github, but when I upgraded my OS even if I tried to configured it again I couldn't, I configured my username but it didn't appears on the git window

Comment: Do you have an `origin` remote? You did not show us any proof that you created one.

Comment: Also just in case, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68057254/after-git-push-u-origin-main-command-git-bash-is-not-requesting-any-authentic

Comment: I am new in this so if my answer is clear or it is not what you meant, please clarify it to me.I have been trying to add origin, if it is done on my terminal it is not connected with github in any way, I cant create or push anything to github, I use the upload files to github.

Answer (score 0):

Then the issue is that you have not configured git to always create new branches on the remote from local ones.

The permanent fix if you always want to just create that new branch on the remote to mirror and track your local branch is:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

Comment: It could be possible that your url is not set correctly. Here it would help if you would share your .git/config

Comment: .git/config: line 1: [core]: command not found
.git/config: line 2: repositoryformatversion: command not found
.git/config: line 3: filemode: command not found
.git/config: line 4: bare: command not found
.git/config: line 5: logallrefupdates: command not found
.git/config: line 6: symlinks: command not found
.git/config: line 7: ignorecase: command not found