# Checking if GitHub is blocked by organisation network

Tags: git, github, firewall, git-push

The organisation has recently rolled out some IT updates - upgraded all our PCs to Windows 10, and also reviewed and updated their security, firewall etc.

It's not my job, so don't know exactly what changes have been made.

I have cloned a repo from GitHub using Git Bash, and configured my user details.

```
git clone https://github.com/.../... .git
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

I can add files to the staging area, commit - everything seems to be working fine locally. I can even pull changes made remotely to my local repo.

However, when I push, very little happens and it hangs.

```
git push -u origin main --verbose
Pushing to https://github.com/.../...
```

I have to exit with `CTRL+C`

The same happens when I try to initialise a repo locally and push it to a blank repository on GitHub, e.g.
https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line

According to the documentation, connectivity issues can be caused when certain traffic is blocked by the organisation network administrator.
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-github/troubleshooting-connectivity-problems

My question is; Is there a way to check whether this is the case without asking the network administrator?

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior on anything other than your computer?

Comment: It could be a well-known bug in Windows Credential Manager: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68057254/7976758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The organisation has recently rolled out some IT updates

Check first the Git version: if, as part of those rolling updates, you have a Git 2.32 (latest one), then you would get the error [I described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68057563/6309), referring to [issue 3264](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3264) or [issue 3268](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3268)

Possible workarounds:

- use the old credential manager: `git config --global credential.helper manager`
- switch to an SSH URL: `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<me>/<myrepo>`
  (assuming you [have set up a public key in your GitHub profile](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh))
  But that is unlikely to work in a corporate setting, where SSH egress is often blocked.

But if your Git version is *not* 2.32, then it would be a connection error, typically due to an HTTPS PROXY not set or incorrectly set.

---

Note (July 2021): [Git for Windows 2.32.0(2)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.32.0.windows.2) should resolve the issue.