# git push command does not work without any error

Tags: git, git-bash

I create a new repository. Clone it to a folder in my computer. Then create a txt file in that folder. When I try to push this changes `$git push` does not work. Even it does not produce any error message. By the way I am using gitbash.

I uninstall gitbash and reinstall it but nothing changes.

The code as follows:

```
~/Desktop/duke/890_r/final_project (main)
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

 ~/Desktop/duke/890_r/final_project (main)
$ git push
```

`$git push` does not produce any error message.

Comment: Could you please provide the full output of the command?

Comment: And provide the exact commands you've run, don't just describe them.

Comment: Where is the cursor after `git push`? If you press `Ctrl+C` is there any error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After $git push -u origin main command, Git bash is not requesting any authentication literally does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68057254/after-git-push-u-origin-main-command-git-bash-is-not-requesting-any-authentic)

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna add `origin main` to the `push` command

```
> git push origin main
```

the reason is because the default branch was `master` but github has changed it to main so gitbash doesn't know what branch to push
so you have to specify that you want to push the `main` branch

if you just want to use the master branch as the default make a new branch named `master` then set `master` as the default [(Github guide)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch) then you could delete the `main` branch [(Delete branch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)

or

You probably pushed into a non-bare repository, i.e. a repository that has a working copy attached to it. You shouldn’t have ignored the warning `git push` gives you if it notices that this is the case.

Anyway, log in to the remote machine, change to the repository and do

```
git checkout <whatever branch you’re on>
```

There you go. Next time only push into bare repositories.

Comment: oh wait yeah this wasn't your problem i'll get you a solution

Comment: i had the exact problem before but i can remember the reason

Comment: try doing 
`$ git push origin main:main`