# Git push doesn't give any response

Tags: github, repository, git-push

I tried to create my repository but when pushing it into github there is no response for  `git push -u origin main` .

Comment: you probably meant `master` instead? by default its a master branch

Comment: @timnaire no in github the dafault is main

Comment: oh i didn't know they already change it, have you try this? `git puh -u origin main:main` ?

Comment: This sounds like https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3294.

Answer (score 0):

If your remote origin is an HTTPS URL, then this is [what I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68057563/6309), as commented: [issue 3264](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3264) or [issue 3268](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3268)

Possible workarounds:

- use the old credential manager: `git config --global credential.helper manager`
- switch to an SSH URL: `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<me>/<myrepo>`
  (assuming you [have set up a public key in your GitHub profile](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh))