# git push takes forever windows

Tags: windows, git, github

I'm trying to commit my repo with following steps

```
git init
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/projectfolder/project/.git/

git add .

git commit -m "test"

git remote add origin https://github.com/me/project.git

git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/me/project.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/me/project.git (push)

git push -u origin main //yes main, not master
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

And it just get stuck.

Typing `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1 GCM_TRACE=1 git push -u origin main` [I see the following](https://pastebin.com/Edfu8TqQ)

It seems to me that the problem is on lines 83 - 86.

So how do I add credentials for my account on git?

Comment: Check first https://stackoverflow.com/q/68057254/6309: this could be a duplicate, especially with Git for Windows 2.32.

Comment: @VonC Despite the link you provided me with didn't help, it gave me an idea to check the windows credentials. So, to Generic Credentials, I added the link on github, my mail, and the password and solved this issue. Nonetheless, I consider this odd, cuz nobody on videos or in docs has done this step. Probably I could also solve it by adding github's certificate to Certificate-Based Credential

Comment: @qwezxc789 So you mean the latest snapshot did not help? (https://wingit.blob.core.windows.net/files/index.html)

Comment: @VonC yeah, didn't help me. I have definitely done something wrong but eventually, with adding the credentials, I manage to push the repository

Answer (score 0):

While the latest [Git for Windows snapshot](https://wingit.blob.core.windows.net/files/index.html) did not help the OP (as part of the [ongoing issue I reported before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68057254/6309)), [qwezxc789](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16135156/qwezxc789) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236057/git-push-takes-forever-windows#comment120599133_68236057):

> it gave me an idea to check the windows credentials.
>
> So, to `Generic Credentials`, I added the link on GitHub, my mail, and the password and solved this issue.
>
> Nonetheless, I consider this odd, because nobody on videos or in docs has done this step.
> Probably I could also solve it by adding github's certificate to Certificate-Based Credential.