# Why is git push origin master command not responding?

Tags: git, github

I want to push into a new repository, but when I enter `git push origin master` command, it doesn't respond, and I can't enter any other command.

When I close it, it pops up a mintty box showing "`Processes are running in session`".
And I am unable to push my project onto GitHub.

Given below is the image of popup:

[image: popup]

How can I get past this error?

Comment: Are you sure that the server of the origin url is working, and the git web request is in timed out ?

Comment: side note : a common way to stop a running process in a terminal is to type `[Ctrl] + [C]`. This sends a signal to that process, instead of killing (and closing) the complete terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Check first:

- your remote URL (`git remote -v`)
- your Git version (`git version`)

If it is an HTTPS one, and you are using Git for Windows 2.32(1), [there was an issue with the credential manager which could freeze a push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68057563/6309).
It is [fixed in 2.32(2)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), so make sure to upgrade and see if the issue persists.