# Simple push of local repository to GitHub not working

Tags: git, github, version-control

I created a repository on GitHub named DogRaces. I did nothing else on GitHub.

On my local computer I ran:

```
git init
```

I committed a file.

git status returns:

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Which is fine I don't want to track certain files.

git branch returns

```
  iss53
* main
```

git remote -v returns:

```
DogRaces        https://github.com/BorutFlis/DogRaces.git (fetch)
DogRaces        https://github.com/BorutFlis/DogRaces.git (push)
```

git push DogRaces returns:

```
fatal: The current branch main has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream DogRaces main
```

SO I run the suggested command and nothing happens it just blocks the shell

If I add -v, I get:

```
Pushing to https://github.com/BorutFlis/Test.git
```

And nothing else happens.

Comment: Windows? Git Bash? Windows Credential Manager?

Comment: git Bash and windows

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68057563/7976758