# Git authentication broken

Tags: git, github

I try to make `git pull` but get this window.

Reinstall git and generate new keys but the same problem, but before I had login and password inputs after reinstall it's `Personal Access Token`. What is the reason and how I can fix this?

[image: 1]

Comment: Do you have your token configured in .git/config?

Comment: No its for all repos

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68057254/after-git-push-u-origin-main-command-git-bash-is-not-requesting-any-authentic

Comment: what is your default editor and also did you try http link instead of ssh?