# git push origin does nothing

Tags: git

I am currently learning how to use the git and github environment, but at the time of executing the code `git push origin main` and give enter, the console does nothing and does not allow me to execute more code.

The codes that I executed were:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git status

git remote add origin https://github.com/USER_NAME/PROJECT_NAME.git
git pull origin main
git push -u origin master
```

In this order, respectively.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Is it `git push origin main` or `git push -u origin master`? And are there any errors?

Comment: I had the same problem. I have written the solution here: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68057254/after-git-push-u-origin-main-command-git-bash-is-not-requesting-any-authentic/68257872#68257872)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS and your `git config credential.helper` value: Git might try and access a credential helper (to cache your GitHub credentials) but fails.

That would explain why a git push (preferably using main: `git push -u origin main`) hangs.

If you are on Windows, make sure to have the latest [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (2.32.0.*2*), as there was a [bug with Git 2.32.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68057563/6309).