# Pull and push doesn't do anything

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, bitbucket

Actually i want to pull and push a repository but when I make git pull doesn't ask for a password, for expample I made a git status a this is the result

```
-> % git status
On branch beta
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/beta' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  modified:   account_dynamic_reports/models/res_company.py
```

git status works well but when I made git pull or git push, the logs doesn't do nothing like this

```
-> % git pull
```

Not even ask for the password

Comment: `git pull` only asks for a password in private repositories. Aside from this, git may save passwords in a credential storage.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68057563/7976758

Answer (score 0):

I would first check if my remote repository is configured properly or not.
you can use `git remote -v` to check if my remote is configured or not.

if No: then configure that first (git remote add origin )

if Yes: then you can modify the config using the git config
`git config --global user.name "Mona Lisa"`
`git config user.email "your_email_address@example.com"`