# Git doesn't ask for username and password in windows 10

Tags: git

I did these steps in project's folder:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/xxxxxxxxx/test.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

but Git bash doesn't ask username or password? something like freeze...

Comment: any error message? you may want to reset credentials in windows security center.

Comment: @LeiYang Yes, no error and warning... by the way I tried with credentials, I added my username and password, but problem exists...

Comment: one possible walkaround is to use [ssh keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account). it's more convenient than username and password.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68057563/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgit%5d%20password%20freeze