# pushing back to github repository

Tags: git, github, push

I cloned one of my github repository to my office desktop machine using the following command

```
git clone git://github.com/indiajoe/MyRepo.git
```

After making some changes, and commiting it, i wasn't able to push back the changes to repository using the command,

```
git push -u orgin master
```

Following was the error message.

```
fatal: 'orgin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried to re-enter the address, as shown below.

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/indiajoe/MyRepo.git
```

Even after this, i was getting the same error.
Output of my git remote -v is

```
origin  https://github.com/indiajoe/MyRepo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/indiajoe/MyRepo.git (push)
```

What could be going wrong here?

PS: While cloning I wasn't able to do via https by the following command

```
git clone https://github.com/indiajoe/MyRepo.git
```

But it cloned without any issue with the command,

```
git clone git://github.com/indiajoe/MyRepo.git
```

I don't know, why this happened. but could this be a related issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git push -u `orgin` `master`
```

That shouldn't work: it is '**`origin`**', *not* '`orgin`' ;)

So, by default, this should work:

```
git push -u origin master
```

(as I detail in "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)")

Comment: Oh god, this is embarrassing. I spent hours trying to figure out what is wrong...

Comment: @indiajoe we've all been there, believe me ;)