# fatal error in git hub when pushing in branch

Tags: github

I want to push to a branch which is not master. That is what I did:

```
    git init
    git add .
    git commit -m "first"
    git push origin second (second is the name of a branch) but it say


fatal: origin does not appear to be a git repository.
fatal: could not read from remote repository.
Please sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Last night I could do that and in the morning suddenly it does not recognize my branch! it does not show my branch when I do git branch, it only shows a master branch. But why I experience this problem sometimes?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are in the right branch: if git branch doesn't list 'second', you can create it:

```
git checkout -b second
```

> Actually "second" branch exists and I can see it on the github site

Then:

```
git checkout -b second --track origin/second
```

(a `git fetch origin` might be in order first)

Then, make sure the remote 'origin' exists:

```
git remote -v
```

And then, push and set `origin/second` as [upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309) of your local branch `second`.

```
git push -u origin second
```

(See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)" for more)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually "second" branch exists and I can see it on the github site. but it does not recognize it from commands.

Comment: @sasha if you want to push from your local repo, you need have it first. see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currenlty I am on master branch and I want to push my files in second branch. but it does not recognize my second branch. last time when I did git push origin master. all my file in amster branch replaced by a file that I wanted to added to second branch. and this time I am really scared to to it again. thats why I only want to check out second. but it says could not read from remote repository!

Comment: @sasha you need first to checkout the second branch, and then add and commit in that branch. What `git remote -v` returns?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
git pull origin master
```

before

```
git push origin master
```

I had the same error and it worked for me.