# Couldn't find remote ref HEAD in Git

Tags: git, version-control, bonobo

I installed bonobo git server on windows 7.

I created a new repository "SFK" through that bonobo.

Then I cloned into that like:

```
git clone http://localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/SFK.git
git add "trans.cs"
git commit -m "added"
git push http://localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/SFK.git
```

Everything works.

Bit When I try to pull using

```
git pull http://localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/SFK.git
```

**It gives this error**

```
fatal:
Couldn't find remote ref HE
Unexpected end of command stream
```

Where am I going wrong? I am new to this git and bonobo.
please suggest how to rectify this.

**UPDATE:**

I tried this after push.

```
git config --global pull.default current
git config --global push.default current
```

It worked.

Comment: Why are you using the full path? If you run the `git clone` then the remote `http://localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/SFK.git` will be set as `origin` by default. Can you try running `git pull origin`?

Comment: You can try Git Candy, A Git platform based on ASP.NET MVC. Source on:http://github.com/Aimeast/GitCandy, Demo on: http://git.53wb.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those settings allow git to know what to push to or what to pull from:

> push the current branch to update a branch with the same name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central workflows.

It should only be:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

(I am not aware of that setting for pull)

I would recommend:

- using the remote name instead of its url: origin
- using a push with makes a tracking connection between your local and **[upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)**:

So:

```
git push -u origin master
git pull origin
```

After that, a simple `git push` will be enough: see "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)" for more.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this after push.

```
git config --global pull.default current
git config --global push.default current
```

I tried this command after i made pull..

Then when i pushed it it works..
Still i need to know the scene behind this ?

Really this is alone reason or ?

If someone figure it please give a reply..