# Failed to push some refs to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I created a new GitHub repository. On my first time trying `git push origin master`, I get this mystifying error:

```
remote: /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:441:in `lstat': No such file or directory - /data/repositories/b/nw/ba/91/bin (Errno::ENOENT)
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:441:in `realpath_rec'
remote:     from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb:474:in `realpath'
remote:     from -e:1
To https://github.com/backseatviolist/lilysmufl
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/backseatviolist/lilysmufl'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Localised to temporary GitHub issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is an error on the remote side (GitHub), it should be linked to some issue GitHub is having those last few hours.

See [GitHub Status history](https://status.github.com/messages)

> Some Pages sites for users that use apex domains are currently unavailable. We're working to resolve the problem as quickliy [*sic*] as possible.

Check if the issue persists (and if it does contact the GitHub support)

Note: for the very first push, try a:

```
git push -u origin master
```

See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".

---

The [OP ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/826565/coldfusion) actually [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506724/failed-to-push-some-refs-to-github/20513182#comment30697022_20513182):

> **Something went wrong during the creation of the repository**;
>   GitHub support suggested I delete it and try again.
>   Issue resolved

Comment: Something went wrong during the creation of the repository; GitHub support suggested I delete it and try again. Issue resolved.

Comment: @ColdFusion Excellent. I have included your feedback in the answer for more visibility.