# Accessing files of a repository from the Git server

Tags: git, repository

I have to access some files stored in a Git repository, but I don't see where they are stored inside the repository folder.

Is there a special way to access the various files pushed from the clients?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a bare repo, you wouldn't find those file in the `repo.git` folder.
See "[all about "bare" repos](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/sitaramc/sitaramc.github.com/blob/dce410b2a2804723676db9cabd7bb506b6d9ba05/concepts/bare.html)": a bare repo has no working tree, and is used for pushing to it (since there is no working tree to keep in sync with an updated branch)

The easiest way to see those file is to clone said bare repo:

```
git clone /path/to/repo.git /path/to/repo
```

Comment: how do you get it updated every time you commit if you only clone it.?

Comment: @zer If you make new commits, you can push back to that bare repo, which will update it.

Comment: I get the idea now thanks i've added a hook post-recieve to pull the latest commit. coming from using svn i am setting up git server now. thanks ( = @vonC

Comment: @zero8 Well done! I used a similar solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48577475/6309

Answer (score 5):

I know only a hack-ish way to see the list of files in a bare repository without cloning:

```
GIT_DIR=/path/to/bare.git git log --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A
```

You most probably want to sort that output and exclude blank lines:

```
GIT_DIR=/path/to/bare.git git log --pretty=format: --name-only --diff-filter=A | sort | grep .
```

Viewing the content of a file is pretty clean though:

```
GIT_DIR=/path/to/bare.git git show HEAD:path/to/file
```

If you want to get specific files out of the bare repository but not entire repository, you could redirect the output of `git show` to a file.

Btw, `GIT_DIR=... git cmd` is equivalent to `git --git-dir=... cmd`

Comment: +1. If only the list is important, this avoid the need to clone the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Git repositories are often stored on the server as a bare repository. This is effectively the contents of the normal `.git` directory, and does not include an extracted working copy.

To access files stored in such a repository I recommend cloning the repository. If you want to do this from the server you can do something like `git clone file /path/to/bare/repository /path/to/clone`.