# Git - post-receive not running on windows

Tags: windows, git, apache

I am running XAMPP server on my Windows Server 2008 R2. I am running Git 64bit version 2.16.1.windows.1
I would like to use `post-receive` hook to update my website after i do pa push from my client.

I created a bare project `MyProject.git` on server and cloned it to `MyProject`.

My hook is:

```
#!C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe 
echo "Hook got triggered.." > hooks.txt
exec powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\hooks\post-receive.ps1"
```

Powershell script is:

```
cd "C:/xampp/htdocs/webapp/myProject/"
git pull origin master
exec git-update-server-info
```

I searched similar questions without any luck for solution of to problem.

If i run the script manually in powershell it runs ok. Based on my log the hook inst even firing.

The Git on Apache looks like it's configured correctly, because i can push to remote without problems and if i do a pull on the server in `MyProject` folder, the files that i get from repo are correct.

What am i missing?

**EDIT:**

I fixed my hook to:

```
#!C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe
echo "Hook got triggered.."
exec powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\hooks\post-receive.ps1"
```

And my powershell script to:

```
cd "C:/xampp/htdocs/webapp/myProject/"
unset GIT_DIR
git pull origin master
exec git-update-server-info
```

Response when i push to remote is:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 296 bytes | 296.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To http://git.mysite.com/myProject.git
  999aeb1..cf0df6f  master -> master
```

There is no "Hook got triggered.." response.

**EDIT2:**
I chaneged my hook to:

```
#!C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe
echo "Hook got triggered.."
cd "C:/xampp/htdocs/webapp/drajv-tecaj/"
unset GIT_DIR
git pull origin master
```

The script runs correctly if executed manually usin bash. But the script is still not running after i do a push on client.

**EDIT3**
Pasting my config for virtual host, that I'm pushing to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/webapp"
    ServerName git.mysite.com
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/webapp">
        Options +ExecCGI +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/">
        Require all granted 
    </Directory>
    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT C:/xampp/htdocs/webapp
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    ScriptAlias /git "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/"
    ScriptAliasMatch \
        "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
                    info/refs | \
                    objects/(info/[Apache Git server on Windows^/]+ | \
                             [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                             pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                    git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
                    "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/$1"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What is the exact name of your post-receive script? it should have *no* file extension.

Comment: The exact file name copied from hooks folder is `post-receive`. The whole path is `C:/xampp/htdocs/webapp/myProject.git/hooks/post-receive` as described in comments of bottom answer

Comment: The issue is still not resolved

Comment: Can you try changing the first line to `#!/bin/sh` (the shebang line), if you haven't tried that combination yet

Comment: Tried that, didnt work. Now my shebang line is `#!/bin/sh;C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe;/usr/bin/env sh;/usr/bin/sh`

Comment: Don't end the shebang line with a semicolon, make it like so: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26546432/

Comment: It's not, jsut the line got splited there in the comment. I file it's all one line. I Included multiple locations. Basicaly trial and error form this point because i don't know where the problem is. The script works if i execute it manauly, the hook just doesn't fire on it's own whene i do a push.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in "[git post-receive not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9905975/6309)", you would need to unset **[`GIT_DIR`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git-codeGITDIRcode)** for your pull to work correctly from within a hook.

```
cd "C:/xampp/htdocs/webapp/myProject/"
unset GIT_DIR
git pull origin master
exec git-update-server-info
```

Comment: Ok, I added that line for the future. But i don't think there is more of a problem that `post-receive` is not firing. Nothing gets added to  `hooks.txt` when i do the push from my client machine. I removed the last part of the line so that i schold get the response  "Hook got triggered.." in my comand window. I edited my question with response that i get when i do a push

Comment: @Nomeaning25 what is the full path and name of your hook on the server side? did you had an extension? (post-receive.txt)

Comment: No, no extensions. The full path to my hooks is `C:/xampp/htdocs/webapp/myProject.git/hooks/`. This is my bare project that I use for remote repo. When i push to remote I push to this project.

Comment: @Nomeaning25 I understand https://tygertec.com/git-hooks-practical-uses-windows/, but just in case, can you try other shebangs, like `#!/usr/bin/env sh` or `#!/usr/bin/sh`?

Comment: @Nomeaning25 by the way, what git version do you have on your server? 2.16.x I suppose?

Comment: Tried both of shebangs but same result. I still dont get anythig from hoot to response. Based on `git --version` i am using 2.16.1.windows.1

Comment: @Nomeaning25 And I presume, in your last two tries, that no files were pulled?

Comment: @Nomeaning25 Just to be sure, your hook is named `post-receive`? As in `C:/xampp/htdocs/webapp/myProject.git/hooks/post-receive`? It should be executable.

Comment: Correct, no files were pulled.

Comment: And you have two different folders, one for the bare repo `C:/xampp/htdocs/webapp/myProject.git` and one for the non-bare repo `C:/xampp/htdocs/webapp/myProject`, with a `.git/` subfolder in it.

Comment: I presume i have to execute it throug GitBash? In command promt it does not work

Comment: The bare repo and non-bare repo are configured as you described

Comment: @Nomeaning25 Yes, bash is needed to run those hook scripts (mainly because of the shebang)

Comment: Yes, I can execute the script using bash. The script executes normaly and pulls my repo. I will edit my question since i edited my script

Comment: Any other ideas? Is it possible that i have something woring in my apache configuration?

Comment: @Nomeaning25 Yes, I suspect the Apache config for calling git might be incorrect. See for instance https://gist.github.com/karmi/484199#file-git-hosting-apache-conf-L55-L68.