# While building a git project from jenkins it shows an error like couldn't find any revision to build

Tags: git, svn, testing, jenkins

While trying to build a git project through jenkins it gives an error 
'ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE'
What does this error means and what should I do to remove it?

Comment: I think this happens because it is a newly created repository and no commits have been done till now. After committing this error may solve.

Comment: The link posted by Abhishek has nothing to do with the question.  It's about a completely unrelated problem.

Comment: @TonyDavis I have a repo with commits still I am getting this error! any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I confirm: an empty repo has no HEAD, and no branch. I mention this in "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)"

That means Jenkins, [once the repo is cloned](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/cf9dd72d9e7c242ae68fd1f6f65048691fab2a28/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.java#L825-L834) won't be able to checkout a branch (since there is none yet).

Answer (score 5):

Please check the name of your branch to see if it is called `main` or `master`.

1. If the branch is called `main`, set the branches to build to `*/main`.
   (By default, GitHub names the default branch `main` in any new repository).
2. If the branch is called `master`, set the branches to build to `*/master`.