# REST-full access: Cannot add file to repository in Gitlab

Tags: git, rest, gitlab

I tried the following request:

```
curl -v -X POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:myPrivateToken" 'url-of-gitlab/api/v3/projects/myProjectId/repository/files?file_path=1.json&branch_name=master&content=thefilecontent&commit_message=ACommitMessage'
```

However, I invariably get

```
"message":"You can only create files if you are on top of a branch"
```

in the response. I don't know what's missing from my request.
The repository is newly created and I created it through the Gitlab UI. Maybe I need to create a branch first? Any help would do. Thank you very much.

Comment: After I've pushed an initial commit to the repo, the API calls started working. The initial push created the master branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The repository is newly created and I created it through the Gitlab UI.

A newly created repo (through GitLab or even a simple `git init` locally) has **no branches** (and no HEAD).
This is what I describe in "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".

> Maybe I need to create a branch first?

Yes, you do (at least a `master` branch)