# what is the difference between `git push` and `git push -u`?

Tags: git, github

I've been using `git push -u origin branch` for a while now. 
but seeing my workmates manage to push a new branch using `git push origin branch` without the switch u got me thinking, what are there main difference? are there any at all?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git help push` will tell you

```
   -u, --set-upstream
       For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add
       upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less git-pull(1)
       and other commands. For more information, see branch.<name>.merge
       in git-config(1).
```

Meaning if you run `git push -u some_repo some_branch` then after the push `some_repo/some_branch` is set as the upstream for the subsequent pulls.

So the next time you have `some_branch` checked out locally and you run `git pull` it will automatically try to pull from `some_repo/some_branch`