# Git error: --all can't be combined with refspecs

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a java based dynamic web project in eclipse which is placed under git for source control. 
I want to upload this project into a repository in bitbucket. To do that, I used the commands 
below -

```
git remote add origin https://myself@bitbucket.org/myself/affablebean.git
git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
```

The second command gives me an error. Please tell me why this happens and how do I fix it.

```
error: --all can't be combined with refspecs
usage: git push [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]

    -v, --verbose         be more verbose
    -q, --quiet           be more quiet.................
    -u, --set-upstream    set upstream for git pull/status
...........................
```

Comment: I tried `git push -all origin` instead and the whole project seems to be uploaded. I am not sure if this
is the correct way to do things.

Comment: No, a `git push -u origin master` is better: see the link I mention in my answer below.

Comment: Both are fine, depends on what you want to do. If you want to "upload (a) project", I'd say --all is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git push` with `-u` sets upstream for a branch, it's a subcommand expecting a refspec (reference specification: branch, commit etc.), so it cannot be used with --all.

`git push --all origin` is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `git push -u origin master` should be enough: no need for `--all`.

That supposes you have added and committed your files locally on the `master` branch.

See more at "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".

Comment: It depends. For the first commit pushing multiple branches it is definitely useful to push everything at once…

Comment: @Knut I agree. But somehow, for a first project to be put under version control, I doubt there were that many branches.

Comment: That might be totally true… :)