# difference between git push -u origin master and git push origin master

Tags: git, push

I have been using git for a while now, and thus far, I have always used

```
git push origin master
```

Recently, however, I have come across

```
git push -u origin master
```

Can someone tell me what the difference between the two is, i.e. what the -u option stands for? I've tried googling quite a bit, but didn't find anything that answered my question.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309

Comment: Thank you, that explains it pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output of `git help push`. According to this, it just tells future calls to `git push` which branch to track.

```
  -u, --set-upstream
       For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add
       upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less git-pull(1)
       and other commands. For more information, see branch.<name>.merge
       in git-config(1).
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I should have thought of checking the help myself.