# Trying To Put Project On Github

Tags: git, github

I am trying to put my project on github following instructions given here:https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line

But is not allowing me to push my project on github showing error:failed to push some refs to . It also shows following hints.

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is to be
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

**

I have tried to figure out the meaning of it but failed.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens if you have created a non-empty GitHub repo (ie one with a `README.md`, a `.gitignore` and a `LICENSE` file): it has at least one commit of its own.

One easy solution is to delete/recreate your GitHub repo (if it was a new one), selecting the option to create an empty repo.
Simpler (if you don't want to keep the GitHub repo history)

```
git push --force -u origin master
```

If you cannot touch the GitHub repo, then you must precede your `git push` with:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Then you can do a:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Note the `-u` option: see "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)" for more.

Comment: Why not a simple force-push? Does GitHub not support that?

Comment: @hvd it does, I simply don't know if the OP want to keep the files or not. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @VonC But why is it necessary to create empty Github repo?? I am new to github as well as git so it would be great if you can answer my question.

Comment: @user297666 because your error message is the direct result of a non-empty repo, with an history of its own. you need to erase that history with the one you made on your local repo (push --force), or rebase your work on top of the history from the GitHub (pull --rebase), or push to an empty repo (delete/recreate)

Comment: Got my answer.This:"Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?" helped a lot. Thanks for providing it.