# How do I git push a branch out of another branch

Tags: git

I created "`my_branch`" while I was on "`release`"

```
git branch my_branch release
```

So now I have this:

```
$ git branch
my_branch
master
* release
```

I do some adds and commits. Then, I want to push `my_branch`, but I expect it to be at the same level as `release`, and not at the `origin / HEAD`. But that's what happen, if I do:

```
git push origin my_branch
```

What is the correct command to have "`my_branch`" out of "`release`" ?

--------------------------- EDIT

If I do my  add/commit after a first  push:

```
git push origin my_branch
git checkout my_branch
git add myfile.txt
git commit -a -m"toto"
git push

fatal: The current branch my_branch has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
git push --set-upstream origin my_branch
```

--------------------------- EDIT 2

```
git branch my_branch release
git push origin my_branch
git checkout my_branch
git add myfile.txt
git commit -a -m"toto"
git push origin my_branch
```

This works. It is showing up as a fork out of release after the first push in gitlab.
After the second push, the commits is shown as head, ahead of master. I now understand what is hapening looking at the gitlab view. The original scenario at the top actually works but I had trouble interpreting it.

Comment: What is the problem with the command, exactly? Did you create additional commits on release that are not visible on my_branch? If not, the command should do exactly what you describe you want done.

Comment: Are you still on `master` or something?

Comment: The problem is in gitlab network graph, I would expect my branch to be "a fork" out of "release". But my git understanding may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct command to have "my_branch" out of "release" ?

`git push origin my_branch` will work: it will create a branch '`my_branch`' in the remote repo `origin`, even though that branch will reference the same commit as the `release` branch.
It will still be a branch independent from `release`.

It won't show a 'fork' in the history of commits in your GitLab server.
It will only show a fork if you:

- `git checkout my_branch`,
- `git add` and `git commit`,
- `git push origin my_branch` again.

The first push might necessitate that you define an upstream branch:

```
 git push --set-upstream origin my_branch
 or for more recent git
 git push -u origin my_branch
```

Comment: @BobYoplait yes, the first push will require to set an upstream branch: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309