# git: pushing a new, empty branch for an empty project?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have an empty project on remote, which I cloned. Now I want to start working on a branch, `testdev` and start working on it without putting any code to master.

```
$ git checkout -b testdev
$ git status
On branch testdev

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Now I try to push this branch to bitbucket

```
$ git push origin testdev

error: src refspec testdev does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://username@bitbucket.org/myremoterepo.git'
```

I tried `git add .` and `git commit -m "msg"` but that is useless as I don't have any files to track or commit. So how do I push an empty branch to an empty project?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you repo is still empty, you might try and create an empty commit, to have *something* to push:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "initial commit"
git push -u origin testdev
```

See also "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".

---

Git 2.35 (Q1 2022) allows information on remotes defined for an arbitrary repository to be read.

See [commit 4a2dcb1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a2dcb1a08008bfc48c32f408e8622bd0c4ca297), [commit 56eed34](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56eed3422cb4605a616daab589b94a843a75651f), [commit 085b98f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/085b98f6cdbe9ed794e19ded00ccd0431c30faa0), [commit fd3cb05](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd3cb0501e175bcac042587cb7bb75e16034a5b7), [commit e083ef5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e083ef5d54707a4bb855e8ac6f6ee0576a020349) (17 Nov 2021) by [Glen Choo (`chooglen`)](https://github.com/chooglen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6d1e149](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d1e149ac04717efff7e0748509036a87cbb95e1), 10 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`remote`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a2dcb1a08008bfc48c32f408e8622bd0c4ca297): die if branch is not found in repository
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Glen Choo</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>

> In a subsequent commit, we would like external-facing functions to be able to accept "struct repository" and "struct branch" as a pair.
> This is useful for functions like `pushremote_for_branch()`, which need to take values from the `remote_state` and branch, even if branch == `NULL`.
> However, a caller may supply an unrelated repository and branch, which is not supported behavior.
>
> To prevent misuse, add a `die_on_missing_branch()` helper function that dies if a given branch is not from a given repository.
> Speed up the existence check by replacing the branches list with a `branches_hash` hashmap.
>
> Like `read_config()`, `die_on_missing_branch()` is only called from non-static functions; static functions are less prone to misuse because they have strong conventions for keeping `remote_state` and branch in sync.

---

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), a misconfigured '`branch..remote`' led to a bug in configuration parsing.

It avoids `branch was not found in the repository`.

See [commit f1dfbd9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1dfbd9ee010e5cdf0d931d16b4b2892b33331e5), [commit 91e2e8f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/91e2e8f63ebd92295ff0eb5f4095f9e1fba8bab0) (31 May 2022) by [Glen Choo (`chooglen`)](https://github.com/chooglen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0b91d56](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b91d563d8d9615d1dc400b7c5e92ebd7933d01d), 10 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`remote.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/91e2e8f63ebd92295ff0eb5f4095f9e1fba8bab0): don't BUG() on 0-length branch names
>
> <sup>Reported-by: "Ing. Martin Prantl Ph.D."</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Glen Choo</sup>

> [4a2dcb1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a2dcb1a08008bfc48c32f408e8622bd0c4ca297) ("`remote`: die if branch is not found in repository", 2021-11-17, Git v2.35.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d1e149ac04717efff7e0748509036a87cbb95e1) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e773545c7fe7eca21b134847f4fc2cbc9547fa14)) introduced a regression where multiple config entries with an empty branch name, e.g.
>
> ```
> [branch ""]
>     remote = foo
>     merge = bar
> ```
>
> could cause Git to fail when it tries to look up branch tracking information.
>
> We parse the config key to get (branch name, branch name length), but when the branch name subsection is empty, we get a bogus branch name, e.g. "`branch..remote`" gives `(".remote", 0)`.
> We continue to use the bogus branch name as if it were valid, and prior to [4a2dcb1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a2dcb1a08008bfc48c32f408e8622bd0c4ca297), this wasn't an issue because length = 0 caused the branch name to effectively be `""` everywhere.
>
> However, that commit handles `length = 0` inconsistently when we create the branch:
>
> - When `find_branch()` is called to check if the branch exists in the branch hash map, it interprets a length of 0 to mean that it should call `strlen` on the char pointer.
> - But the code path that inserts into the branch hash map interprets a length of 0 to mean that the string is 0-length.
>
> This results in the bug described above:
>
> - "`branch..remote`" looks for "`.remote`" in the branch hash map.
>   Since we do not find it, we insert the `""` entry into the hash map.
> - "`branch..merge`" looks for "`.merge`" in the branch hash map.
>   Since we do not find it, we again try to insert the `""` entry into the hash map.
>   However, the entries in the branch hash map are supposed to be appended to, not overwritten.
> - Since overwriting an entry is a BUG(), Git fails instead of silently ignoring the empty branch name.
>
> Fix the bug by removing the convenience `strlen` functionality, so that 0 means that the string is 0-length.

---

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), fix `git remote` use-after-free (with another forget-to-free) fix.

See [commit 323822c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/323822c72be59ce2900cc036c5bad4f10bafbb53), [commit 338959d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/338959da3e46340dfcec3af361c6062c3a992668) (07 Jun 2022) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fe66167](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe66167535dd8b395f16fcba7863c36beb365ef9), 13 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`remote.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/323822c72be59ce2900cc036c5bad4f10bafbb53): don't dereference NULL in freeing loop
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Fix a bug in [fd3cb05](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd3cb0501e175bcac042587cb7bb75e16034a5b7) ("`remote`: move static variables into per-repository struct", 2021-11-17, Git v2.35.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d1e149ac04717efff7e0748509036a87cbb95e1) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e773545c7fe7eca21b134847f4fc2cbc9547fa14)) where we'd `free(remote->pushurl[i])` after having `NULL`'d out `remote->pushurl`.
> itself.
> We free "`remote->pushurl`" in the next "`for`"-loop, so doing this appears to have been a copy/paste error.
>
> Before this change GCC 12's `-fanalyzer` would correctly note that we'd dereference `NULL` in this case, this change fixes that:
>
> ```
> remote.c: In function ‘remote_clear’:
> remote.c:153:17: error: dereference of NULL ‘*remote.pushurl’ [CWE-476] [-Werror=analyzer-null-dereference]
>   153 |                 free((char *)remote->pushurl[i]);
>       |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       [...]
> ```