# No master branch in git / BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm new to git. I'm using bitbucket with sourcetree client. 
I've cloned the repository from bitbucket in the sourcetree ,and then I wanted to create a Develop branch from Master. 
The thing is : there isn't any master branch. I've tried committing some text file , and then I was able to create that Develop branch , but I still don't see master branch in BitBucket ,so I can't create pull requests from the Develop branch to master...

What have I done wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Please paste the output of `git branch -vva` to your question.

Comment: Is it a brand new empty repo created on BitBucket? Because a new Git repo has no branch initially (as I pointed out in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)

Comment: Yes, I have a remote repository(if I'm correct) opened in bitbucket , a folder of the tasks I need to submit (through Jira). Now I had to create a branch from the master branch , and then create a pull request between them so that my tasks can be examined.

Comment: @ckruczek
Here's the output :
* Development_v0.1                17f7dbb no message  |
  master                          17f7dbb [origin/master: gone] no message  |
  remotes/origin/Development_v0.1 b647f22 no message

Comment: Please format your code better next time. But for me it looks like you do have a `master` branch

Comment: why can't I see it in BitBucket under Branches section?
I can only create branches from the Development branch..

Comment: Well it looks like you really just have the master branch on local and not on remote. Was the repository a brand new one, than most of the repos do not have any branch. That would explain the situation.

Comment: But doesn't master branch should be local in fact? I mean , every repository has its own master branch ? or a master branch is a remote branch which is mutual to all the local repositories cloned from it?

most importantly - how do I create a pull request between master and Development ? I see only Development branch in bitbucket..

Comment: If you create a initial repository there is no branch at all. You to create it with the first commit. On your local machine you do have a master as I can see from your output and it points to the commit `17f7dbb` But obviously you haven't pushed this one.

Comment: So does it work that way : Original/head is like a remote master branch. Then I have my local master branch . and from it I create another branches like Development ?

Answer (score 6):

`master` is just a name for the usual default branch. But it doesn’t need to be called that way. If you do `git branch -r` you can see what branches exist on your remote, so you know which branch you could create a pull request for.

If you really want a master branch, you could just create a new branch.

Comment: Thank you.
I'm using sourceTree client. Is there an option for command lines there?

Comment: You can tick the “show remote branches” option at the top to see remote branches in your history.

Comment: I've got two lines (btw, I'm using Mac if it's important) :
1. (at the description: ) "master" , and then "develop" no message.
2. (at the description: ) "origin/develop" no message.

Comment: So there seems to be only a develop branch on the remote then; then provide a pull request for that branch.

Comment: * Development_v0.1                17f7dbb no message   |

  master                          17f7dbb [origin/master: gone] no message   |  

  remotes/origin/Development_v0.1 b647f22 no message

Answer (score 4):

If you will try to clone the empty repository, while cloning you should be getting the following message in command line prompt.

```
Cloning into 'test'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

So, it means you are starting a project from scratch. In this case you have to follow the following steps -

```
mkdir /path/to/your/project
cd /path/to/your/project
git init
git remote add origin "Your Repo Url"
git add -A
git commit -m 'Your Commit Message'
git push -u origin master
```

Same streps are also mentioned in bitbucket home page of your repository. It will create your master branch.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your repository with your username and name, after that your master branch will be created and you will be able to commit your code.

```
git config --global user.email "your@email.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bitbucket, commit the default `README.md` file that Bitbucket offers to generate. The master branch will be created upon committing the `README.md` file.

Comment: Where in Bitbucket does it offer to create a default README.md file?

Answer (score -1):

In BitBucket,

Click on Commits, and commit any file (A sample readme and .gitignore file).
It will be automatically commited to the master branch.

And then you will be able to see the master branch and can create new branches also.

Comment: This is not true (at least in early 2018)