# How does initializing a repository with a README help in letting you immediately clone the repository to your computer?

Tags: git, github

[image: github repository creation]
How are they connected in any way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

git can perfectly clone an empty repository.

But in that case, you end-up with a repo with *no branch*, which can be unsettling for Git beginners.

That also means that, when you create your own commit in that empty cloned repo, you need to setup the [upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309) on the first push, with a `git push -u origin master`.
Again, a bit of a hassle when you discover Git.
See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)"

Hence the recommendation for creating at least one file, meaning at least one commit in a `master` branch.
Plus, the cloned repo now has a local `master` branch with its upstream branch *already setup*: when new commits are done locally, a simple `git push` is enough to send them to the GitHub repo.

Those two points (local repo with a `master` branch, *and* with a remote tracking branch `origin/master`) make for an easier experience.

If you are importing an existing repo, on the other hand, you would want an empty repo to begin with.