# Can git ever send your code to a repo that isn't yours?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-add, git-init

Can running

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
```

in a git repo which you've initialized using

```
git init
```

ever result in your code being sent to a repo that is not yours? I am concerned because I did this while not logged in to my git hub account.

Comment: Aeehm...please what ?!

Comment: Please what? `git init` does not have anything to do with pushing? Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Also git is not github

Comment: git is not github, but when logged in and committing, git gives the message:   
           
"Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author
" 
and provides me with the username to my github account. So I felt this was relevant

Comment: @yaboi This just means that Git is choosing a default name and email.  It doesn't mean that any information left your local machine.

Comment: I now understand that, my comment was in response to @Phil_1984_ to clarify why I mentioned my git hub account in my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a `git commit` locally won't result in your code being sent to *any* repo, let alone a repo which is not yours.  When you do a `git commit`, Git will add some *local* objects corresponding to the changes you have made in the current working branch.

In order for code to leave your local machine, you would need to issue a `git push`, which by default will try to send the `master` branch to whatever remote is contained in `origin`.

Even if you accidentally did a `git push` to an unknown repository, it would most likely be rejected for many reasons.  First, in the case of GitHub, you would not have to rights to make the push.  Even if you somehow did have the right to push, either the branch names might not be the same, or it would be rejected as not being a fast forward.

Git has many safeguards to prevent this sort of thing from happening.

Comment: Possible edit to this answer based on @VonC's response. The push would definitely be rejected because "you wouldn't have the right to push to a GitHub repo you don't own or you are not a collaborator of anyway"

Answer (score 2):

No, this (add and commit) is purely local to your repo.

You would need to add a remote (`git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/<repo>`) and push ([`git push -u origin master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)) for that to happen (and you wouldn't have the right to push to a GitHub repo you don't own or you are not a collaborator of anyway).