# Git (hub) Beginner Problems

Tags: git, github

While working on my first project using Github, I ran into a few problems. I started using the xCode source control but then switched to using terminal.

1) I seem to have duplicates when I try to look at my remote directories.

```
$ git remote -v
NavCtrl https://github.com/.../projectabc.git (fetch)
NavCtrl https://github.com/.../projectabc.git (push)
NavCtrl https://github.com/.../projectabc.git (fetch)
NavCtrl https://github.com/.../projectabc.git (push)
```

Is it safe to delete one of them since they have the same exact name.

2) When I push, is there a difference in me using

```
$ git push origin master
```

and

```
$ git push origin projectabc/master
```

3) Can I safely just continue using the terminal without doing anything in xCode. In other words, do I have to somehow delete the source control from xCode to avoid running into problems? If yes, how do I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ Yes you can delete the double entry, by editing the `.git/config` file in your repo

2/ `git push origin projectabc/master` would push the local branch `projectabc/master` to the remote repo origin.
It is best to stick with `git push origin master` (or better: `git push -u origin master` for the first push, and `git push` for the next ones: see "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)")

3/ In theory, yes: it can depends on your version of XCode, but it (XCode) should be able to synchronize with the new git repo status once you have done your modifications with the command-line.

Comment: remote.projectabc.url=https://github.com/username/projectabc.git
remote.projectabc.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/projectabs/*
branch.master.remote=projectabc
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.Assignment3.remote=projectabc
branch.Assignment3.merge=refs/heads/projectabc
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/usernam/projectabc.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*  
  
which one would i delete?

Comment: @BorisR Actually in that case, none: you do have two remotes (projectabc and origin). In that regard, the output of `git remote -v` is expected.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! @VonC