# performing git push with repo URL pre set

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

every time I have to push my branch to remote on GitHub I have to run the following command,

```
git push --set-upstream sensorAtHome WIP
```

however at office I just go ahead and push to our company cgit server.

so what is different and what do I need to do, locally for my GitHub project 
I have a already done this:

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

I thought that was enough .

secondly what `<name>` refers to name of branch or name of repository?

Comment: `<name>` is the name of the remote. It's the name you're gonna use to refer to that `<url>`. `sensorAtHome` is a remote name. As for the rest of your problem, `git push --set-upstream` should do it. Could you show the ***full text*** of what happens when you run that command? Also the content of `.git/config` in that repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `git branch -avv` output, as well as `git remote -v`

Your office branch is probably already linked to a remote tracking branch.

See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)"

You should push once with:

```
git push -u sensorAtHome WIP
```

Then a  simple git push would be enough: your local branch would know where and to which branch to push ("where" is `sensorAtHome` remote url, and "which branch" is `sensorAtHome/WIP`)