# untracked file in git when creating the respository

Tags: wordpress, github

I have a wordpress project that I would to push there files in my repository.

First, when I commit, I have this message :

```
Untracked files:
        wordpress/
```

Nothing added to commit but untracked files present.

After, when I use "`git push origin master`", I have this :

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/islem98/ProjetWordPress.git'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to add files to the repository using the `git add` command. Then you need to commit those files using the `git commit` command. You may also want to use the `-u` flag if the git remote is empty.

Comment: You may want to brush up your git knowledge with something like https://try.github.io

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add first, then commit, to have a local commit to push to your remote repo.

```
git add wordpress
git commit -m "Add wordpress"

git push -u origin master
```

Note: the `-u` will set `origin/master` as the **[upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)** for your local `master` branch, enabling you to use a simple `git push` for the next commits you want to put in your remote GitHub repo.
See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".

Comment: See more at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository