# Git can't connect to remote using private ssh file

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I'm using the (relatively) new Git sshCommand:

```
git config core.sshCommand  'ssh -i ~/Documents/keydir/key.pem'
```

This results in the following config:

```
sshCommand = ssh -i ~/Documents/keydir/key.pem
```

But when I try to push to the server (btw I'm using the home directory. Does it have to be the www directory?)

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://ubuntu@myserver.com:22/home/ubuntu/myrepo.git
```

or

```
[remote "origin"]
            url = ssh://ubuntu@myserver.com/home/ubuntu/myrepo.git
```

It returns the:

```
git push remote master
fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

...error.

Haven't been able to figure it out.

I've tried using "~/myrepo.git" and "/home/ubuntu/myrepo.git" and I've also tried "url = ssh://ubuntu@myserver.com:/home/ubuntu/myrepo.git"

I've also tried starting a new  git in the /var/www folder...

Nothing seems to work. And the myrepo.git is definitely there in the ubuntu home folder.

Any ideas?

EDIT: My complete .git/config file:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
        sshCommand = ssh -i ~/Documents/keydir/key.pem
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://ubuntu@myserver.com:22/home/ubuntu/mygit.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

**EDIT:** Updating both local (2.5.4) and remote (2.7.4) versions of Git to the latest version (2.16.1) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first to check if you can ssh to that server:

```
ssh -Tv -i ~/Documents/keydir/key.pem ubuntu@myserver.com
```

In other words, you must make sure the key.pub *public* key to the `~ubunutu/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Then the command must be:

```
 git push -u origin master
```

This is only for the first time you will push that branch: see "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)"

The URL is correct: adding or removing the port 22 does not matter, since it is the default SSH port.

As [per discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163996/discussion-between-mystic-cola-and-vonc), both ends (local and remote) uses a fairly old version of Git (2.5.4 on MacOS and 2.7.4 on Ubuntu).
Upgrading them both has helped.

Comment: I can "ssh -i" into the server just fine. But with "git push -u origin master" I'm getting: "Permission denied (publickey)."... which I don't get given that I can ssh onto the server just fine. Do I need to make a different key from the pem? Or is it because I'm in the home folder... or...

Comment: Do you have a GIT_SSH_COMMAND environment variable set? (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coresshCommand) Or a GIT_SSH one (https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git-codeGITSSHcode)

Comment: ssh command is setup exactly like I had it in the question. sshCommand = ssh -i ~/Documents/keydir/key.pem

Comment: @mysticcola My point: what you have setup in your question would be overridden by an environment variable. Hence my question.

Comment: In that case the answer is "not to the best of my knowledge." I would flat-out say "no"... because I never set that... then again it's a used laptop so I can't be sure. I'd bet on "no" though. Is there a way I can check?

Comment: @mysticcola What is your local OS and Git version? The command `env` should help seeing environment variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163996/discussion-between-mystic-cola-and-vonc).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `git push` command (“`git push remote master`“) is incorrect.

Try using `git push origin master` instead.

(You may also need to verify that the `myrepo.git` file is actually a git repo, initialized by the git command. The URL you’ve specified seems to follow the correct format as specified in [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).)