# git push request from branch to master

Tags: git, github

I am new to GIT and GITHUB and was doing some hands-on and bit curious whats the best practices when working in the branch.

I did the following :

1. Created a branch (lets say branch9).
2. Added a new file, then git add , git commit.
3. I didn't merge it with master "git merge master"
4. Instead I used this cmd "git push origin master" (so pushing the contents directly to master instead of pushing it to branch9)
5. I see some weird things. I created a pull request from GITHUB and merged the files to master but after few mins the merge disappears.

What is the correct sequence of steps I need to do while working on branching in GIT?

Do I need to merge the contents from branch9 to master in local repo (git merge master) and then `git push origin master`?

Comment: 1. there are many possible workflows. Most of them are described in the freely available online git book. 2. No.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a branch, you are supposed to push that branch:

```
git checkout -b branch9
# git add + commits
git push -u origin branch9

# some more commits
git push
```

Note the second push does not specify origin anymore: see "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)".

Then you can create a pull request from `branch9` to `master` if you want, or if you are the only one working on the repo, you can merge locally your `branch9` to `master`.
If there were no commits on `master`, that merge would be a fast-forward one, which explains why the merge disappear: `master` simply update itself to reflect `branch9` HEAD.