# Successfully created projecton GitHub, but initial push failed: no current branch

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I cannot push project to github, I have this message:

```
"Successfully created project 'SuperUpTest' on GitHub, but initial push failed: no current branch"
```

Attached image of commits
[image: image description]

I need help since i am afraid to break something i really need to push it with all commits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096311/why-do-i-need-to-explicitly-push-a-new-branch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to photo your current branch has strange name "!" or your had detached from master. In current situation I suggest you next steps:

- Create another branch (lets name this branch develop) with command

  `git checkout -b develop`
- Merge new created branch to master

  `git checkout master`
  `git merge develop`
- Explicitly push your commits (maybe you have to use also `--force` option after `-u`)

  `git push -u origin master`
- (Optional) Delete develop branch with `git branch -d develop`

I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a branch first.

`git checkout -b master`

then you can push

`git push origin master`

Or optionally, instead of the above 2 commands. Just run this single command:

`git push -u origin master`

Comment: I did it but the it uploaded commits until the master flag, the some commit the was not pushed

Comment: how to change the master to the last commit?