# Why is the remote branch name in git "origin", and not "master"?

Tags: git, github, push, git-branch

I find it interesting that the remote branch name to be used when pushing back to the remote git repository is named "origin" when it's actually called "master"... Why is this the case?

Comment: Actually, it is `origin/master`.

Comment: Origin refers to the remote server, not the branch. You can have multiple remotes set up for the same local repository. Origin is the default name for the one that the repo was cloned from.

Comment: Also worth remembering: the Git on the remote, i.e., the Git that *you* call `origin`, is a Git repository. It has *its own* branches, including *its* `master`. What you call `origin/master` is your Git's way of remembering *their* `master`, which they just call `master`. (They have no name for your `master` as they have no need to remember that you even exist :-) .)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main advantage for `origin`, which reference *where* to push, is that it is the *default* name for a remote repository reference.

So your first push of your local master branch should be:

```
git push -u origin master
```

(See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)")

But after that, `master` is linked to `origin/master`, and a simple `git push` will be enough, which defaults to `git push origin` (`git push` *to* `origin` the current branch)

Answer (score 7):

`master` is the name of a branch. `origin` is the name of a remote. A remote is a complete git repository that may contain many symbolic branch names; you're generally trying to push your commits from your local `master` to the remote's  - `origin/master` in this case.