# I can't push to branch "dev" in Github using CircleCi

Tags: github, circleci

I am trying to configure autopush to the branch dev in github, using CircleCi. The problem is that I get an error like:

> "error: src refspec dev does not match any.
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:myname/repo.git'.
>   Exited with code 1".

When I am using `git remote -v`, I can see:

```
origin  git@github.com:myname/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:myname/repo.git (push)
```

And on the github required branch "dev" exists. Below you can see the part of my *yml code for CircleCi that makes everything.

```
  - run:
      name: Git config email
      command: git config --global user.email "name@mail.ru"
  - run: 
      name: Git config name
      command: git config --global user.name "Name"
  - run:
      name: git remote -v
      command: git remote -v
  - run:
      name: Push to dev
      command: git push origin dev --force
```

Comment: Also, i thoung, thet the problem is lack of commit, but i also tried:
`add .

git commit -m "Commit to dev"`

And the resul was:
**On branch my_branch
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Exited with code 1**

Comment: When i am trying to `git show-ref`, i can see next:
`8ab8123caee6ea99b34bb8fdac4e626ec20e43ac refs/heads/my_branch
8ab8123caee6ea99b34bb8fdac4e626ec20e43ac refs/heads/master
6d629cafb48677bb598f9d24e87654fd2b8dff8c refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
8ab8123caee6ea99b34bb8fdac4e626ec20e43ac refs/remotes/origin/my_branch
4a16ca86e21710df72b5b7405502b59850428484 refs/remotes/origin/dev
6d629cafb48677bb598f9d24e87654fd2b8dff8c refs/remotes/origin/master`
So, here is nothing like refs/heads/dev, how can i add it?

Comment: made `git checkout dev` and  `refs/heads/dev ` appeared, but the command `git push origin dev` do not pushed changes into git branch "dev".

Answer (score 0):

> `git checkout dev` and `refs/heads/dev` appeared, but the command `git push origin dev` do not pushed changes into git branch "`dev`".

That would create a local `dev` branch based by default on `origin/dev`.

You would need to merge `my_branch` to `dev` first before pushing

```
git merge my_branch
git push
```

(`git push` should be enough, since the newly local created branch `dev` has `origin/dev` for its [upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309))