# When do we need to use --track command in git

Tags: git, github

I have two branches in GitHub, `master` & `testbranch`. When ever I am creating a new branch, I type following git command to create a new branch `git checkout -b testbranchnew`. So in what scenario should I use `git checkout --track origin/testbranchnew` ? Could someone please advise ?
`

`Branches`

1. master
2. testbranch

Comment: Side note: `--track` is not a command, it's an option to several commands. You never *have to* use it (as in, nothing in Git forces you to work this way) but it's quite convenient in a few situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't have to use `git checkout` anymore. Since [Git 2.23 (Aug. 2019)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), there is [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch)

Second, you only have to use --track to set the upstream branch for a local branch, if the name of the upstream branch *differs* from the local one.

That assumes your local repo, in which you are creating a local branch:

- has a remote repository (generally referenced as origin)
- has fetched said remote repository (remote branches are fetched to your local repo)

By default, `--track` is used automatically: from [`git switch` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess)

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git switch -c <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

So in that case, you don't even have to use `--track`.

And if the remote branch does not yet exist, a `git push -u origin yourBranch` would automatically set the upstream relationship between the local and remote branch. See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)". Again, in that case, no need for `--track`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't track anything, then pushing from `testbranch` will be

```sh
git push origin testbranch
```

If instead you were tracking origin/testbranch, then you could just do

```sh
git push
```

from `testbranch` and it'll be pushed to `origin/testbranch`.

I typically do

```sh
git push -u origin HEAD
```

on my first push from a new branch (so it tracks its counterpart on origin) and then `git push` after that.