# I cant push to the "main" default branch

Tags: github

I just created a new repo and it had the "main" branch as the default branch. When I try to push to main I get the following error

error: failed to push some refs to

However, if I create a new branch master, I can push to it without any problem.

Comment: Post the entire error you get and the command you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your [first push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309), assuming your are on the local branch main yourself, you would do:

```
git push -u origin main
```

If you are on a local `master` branch:

- First, make sure any new local repository is created with the default branch "`main`" (see [`init.defaultBranch`](https://github.blog/2020-07-27-highlights-from-git-2-28/#introducing-init-defaultbranch))
- Second, [rename your `master` branch as `main`](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/git-rename-master-to-main/)

  ```
  git branch -m master main
  ```

Then the `git push -u origin main` will work.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. What does the "-u" and "-m" mean?

Comment: It works..but, I dont know why or how..can you elaborate a little bit, Thanks.

Comment: @ElectronDevTools007 Regarding the -u, see my anwer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309

Comment: @ElectronDevTools007 -m rename the branch: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--m